# Removing timestamp fields from the schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I had used default generator to create some tables and they all had that `t.timestamp` in their definition so the schema that was created also has created_at and updated_at fields.
Now I am told that I don't need those two fields in my schema so I went to the original create_table*  files and took out t.timestamp line from them and ran the `db:migrate` and `schema:load` commands 
But still when I go to my schema.rb file I can see they are still there.

Is there anything wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run

```
rails g migration remove_timestamps_from_table created_at updated_at
```

with `table` being your model's name. Since this is following the pattern remove x from y, rails is smart enough to generate the appropriate migration for you.

Then run

```
rake db:migrate
```

to update your development database and

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

to prepare the test database, and you're all set!

Read more on migrations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html). If you are still having trouble, consider restarting your rails server or database server.

Comment: In addition, you'll also want to go back and revert the changes you made to the original migrations as you should not be editing migrations you have already run, especially if you have not rolled them back first.